# Как перенести и обновить данные в Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

У меня есть два файла Access, в них по две таблицы - которые абсолютно одинаковые. Я ввел в таблицу А в БД-1 новые данные, и мне нужно их перенести в таблицу А в БД-2. Можно ли это как-то реализовать?

Comment: Дропнуть старую таблицу и импортировать новую. делов-то...